# Nodemailer transporter — how do I access standard mail fields?

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, nodemailer

I'm writing a simple [nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com) transporter but I'm having trouble finding where the actual mail message data structure is documented.

My `send` method looks like this

```
send: function(mail, callback) {
  var data = {
    messageId: mail.message.getHeader('message-id'),
    from: mail.message.from,
    to: mail.message.to
  }
  console.log('data', data)
  // do stuff with data
  // etc
};
```

when I try this with a message such as:

```
var MYTestTransport = require('./');
var email = {
  headers: {
    'message-id': 'a very nice test'
  },
  from: "Bob <bob@test.tes>",
  to: "Alice <alice@test.tes>",
  subject: "Great Idea",
  text: 'This is a test.',
  html: '<p>This is a <strong>test</strong></p>'
};
var transport = nodemailer.createTransport(MYTestTransport());

transport.sendMail(email, function(err, data) {
  expect(err).to.not.exist;
  expect(data.messageId).to.equal('a very nice test');
  expect(data.from).to.equal('Bob <bob@test.tes>');
  expect(data.to).to.equal('Alice <alice@test.tes>')
  done()
});
```

however `data` ends up being

```
{
  messageId: 'a very nice test',
  to: undefined,
  from: undefined,
  subject: undefined
}
```

How do I read the message fields correctly? Is this documented anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

As per [git example](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer#tldr-usage-example), write `from` and `to` as:

```
var email = {
   headers: {
  'message-id': 'a very nice test'
},
from: '"Bob" <bob@test.tes>',
to: '"Alice" <alice@test.tes>',
subject: "Great Idea",
text: 'This is a test.',
html: '<p>This is a <strong>test</strong></p>')
};
```

Comment: makes no difference.